# How to detect TAB key in BASH?

Tags: bash, keystroke

I have this piece of bash code below,

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
read -rsn1 input
if [ "$input" = "a" ]; then
    echo "triggered"
fi
done
```

It works fine when I press "a" key, however what I really want is trigger something when user press TAB key. How can I make it work? Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the scanning to be split with `IFS`, then set `IFS` to empty.

```
IFS= read -rsn1 input
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I want the script to check if user has pressed TAB key, if yes then I will trigger some action. I know if they press "a" or "b", but I don't know how to capture TAB.

Comment: @JeffWen with the default `IFS`, `read` will strip spaces tabs and newlines, that's why you need to set it empty. then you can test `if [[ $input == $'\t' ]] ...`

Comment: `IFS= read -rsn1 input` Captures TAB in variable `input`.

Comment: Many thanks all, understand now, cheers!